# Error in the filter (bug) parameter chrome chrome.webNavigation.onBeforeNavigate.addListener

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, listener

In this code below

```
const filter = {
  url: [
    { urlEquals: "https://www.amazon.com/" },
    { urlEquals: "https://www.americanas.com.br/" },
  ],
};
chrome.webNavigation.onBeforeNavigate.addListener(
  handleListenerBeforeNavigate,
  {
    url: [
      { urlEquals: "https://www.amazon.com.br/" },
      { urlEquals: "https://www.americanas.com.br/" },
    ],
  }
);

async function handleListenerBeforeNavigate(details) {
  console.log("filter", filter);
  const hostname = new URL(details.url).hostname;
  console.log("Hostname:", hostname);

  return true;
}
```

It presents the following issue: when switching from the Google URL to the Amazon URL in the tab, often the listener is not triggered on the second URL

Google Chrome: Versão 121.0.6167.185

when switching from the Google URL to the Amazon URL in the tab, often the listener is not triggered on the second URL

Comment: Are you sure the URL in the address bar is exactly equal and doesn't have anything after `/` in those occurrences when it fails? Try removing the entire filter parameter and inspect `details.url` in such navigations to find what's different.